# How to post on wall when app is in development mode?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a new web app in development mode, and am trying to post to a users wall using something like this:

```
<fb:login-button scope="publish_pages" autologoutlink="true" onlogin="OnRequestPermission();">
</fb:login-button>

...
var params = {};
params['message'] = 'Message';
params['name'] = 'Name';
params['description'] = 'Description';
params['link'] = 'http://www.example.com';
params['picture'] = 'http://example.com/example.png';
params['caption'] = 'Caption';

FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        console.log(response.error);
    } else {
        alert('Published to stream - you might want to delete it now!');
    }
});
```

I am testing this after a successful login using the FB account defined in that app as admin, but am getting an OAuthException error:

"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform the action"

Do I need to send the app through review to get additional access even though we are in testing? Is there something else I missed here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong permission, you would need `publish_actions` to post to the user wall. `publish_pages` is for posting to a Page you own. You do not need to go through the review process for testing, all permissions work without review for users with a role in the App.

Comment: That is exactly it. Thank luschn